# How do I iterate through a number of sprites frame by frame when i move my character to the right?

Tags: html, sprite, ranged-loops

I have never made a html5 game before and i made some sprites for a simple crossing game. I would like to make my character use a array of four different sprite frames when moving to the right and then cycle through till the last one until i stop moving, where by it then reverses the loop and cycles back to the original sprite frame.
I would like to have that function for both left and right movement. I want the same function but with sprites facing the opposite way when moving left.
If my character collides with a enemy sprite i want the fifth sprite frame for each direction to trigger and stay the sprite when game over. It is a game over sprite which two exist, one for each direction the player was moving when they collided with the enemy. total sprites for player is 10, five for each direction of which four are used each way unless a collision happens where the fifth of the particular direction is triggered.

The enemy sprites consist of only two frames that cycle over and over infinitly until the game is over.

The last frame is for the goal which is a static frame which does not change.

How can I make this work?

I am new so i have no idea if or how exactly I should build a array to cycle through the images for each direction or if i should do some for loop or if loop or for eachloop?

Answer (score 0):

To get a cycling index from an incrementing number, use the modulo operator:

```
sprite_index = step_number % 4
```

then `sprite_index` will be 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,0,1,2,3,... as `step_number` increases like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11...

Don't use a loop because you will already have a loop for moving the characters and so on anyway. An extra loop inside that will stop the main loop while it runs.